# Output file location and contents based on list of files

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cat

I have a file that contains locations of different files called `locationfile.txt` it contains:

```
/home/user/documents/file1
/home/user/file2
/home/user/file3
```

Each text files have about 10 lines and I want to output all files to another file called `finalfile`.

I figured out that if I do

```
cat locationfile.txt | while read line; do cat "$line"; done
```

This prints all files together so it becomes a ~30 line text file.

What my question is, how can I spit that file out put include the file locations inbetween the text like this:

```
/home/user/documents/file1
text
text
text
""
/home/user/file2
text
text
text
""
/home/user/file3
text
text
text
""
```

Answer (score 8):

Before the `cat` do an `echo` or `printf` of the filename:

```
while read line; do printf '%s\n' "$line"; cat "$line"; done <locationfile.txt >finalfile
```

Or, more readable:

```
while read line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  cat "$line"
done <locationfile.txt >finalfile
```

Note that this requires all paths in `locationfile.txt` to have no `\` in them.

Although having `\` in path names is highly unusual, it would be safer to do

```
while read -r line; do
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
  cat "$line"
done <locationfile.txt >finalfile
```

... which doesn't have the same restrictions.

Adding a check to make sure the file actually exist too, and outputting a warning if it doesn't:

```
while read -r line; do
  if [[ -f "$line" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    cat "$line"
  else
    printf 'Warning: "%s" does not exist\n' "$line" >&2
  fi
done <locationfile.txt >finalfile
```

"Does not exist" here means "is at least not a regular file".

If you want the `""` there as well, as a sort of end-of-file-contents-marker, just put that out after `cat`:

```
while read -r line; do
  if [[ -f "$line" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
    cat "$line"
    echo '""'
  else
    printf 'Warning: "%s" does not exist\n' "$line" >&2
  fi
done <locationfile.txt >finalfile
```

And finally, give things self-documenting names:

```
while read -r file_path; do
  if [[ -f "$file_path" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "$file_path"
    cat "$file_path"
    echo '""'
  else
    printf 'Warning: "%s" does not exist\n' "$file_path" >&2
  fi
done <file_paths.txt >files_concat_with_paths.txt
```

Comment: `while read line` works with spaces in file names. And since here is no splitting of the inputl, you don't need to set IFS. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @xhienne You're not missing anything, that is correct. Setting `IFS` to be empty also disables the removal of initial and trailing whitespace in the input, which I usually want to retain, but which may cause problems here. I will amend the answer.

Comment: @xhienne, pretty sure *multiple consecutive* spaces will still be mishandled, but perhaps that's only on initial and trailing whitespace.

Comment: @Wildcard You are right, both of you, leading and trailing spaces are not stored in `line`. But multiple consecutive inner spaces are. And if you don't specify `line`, the whole line goes into `$REPLY`, including leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: @xhienne ... with `IFS=`, yes.

Comment: If you are referring to `REPLY`, the whole line goes into it regardless of IFS.

Comment: @xhienne Um, yes. Awkward. In `ksh93` (which I used when testing before my last reply), `read` behaves just like `read var`, with and without `IFS=`.  GOOD TO KNOW!

Answer (score 3):

```
while read file; do
    ( echo "$file"; cat "$file"; echo '"""' ) >> /path/to/outputfile
done < /path/to/filelist
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an option if you have GNU awk, that avoids shell loops altogether:

```
xargs -d '\n' -a locationfile.txt gawk 'BEGINFILE{print FILENAME} 1' > newfile
```

or with GNU sed:

```
xargs -d '\n' -a locationfile.txt sed -s '1F' > newfile
```

If you don't care about the exact format of the filenames, then you can use this trick with `head`:

```
xargs -d '\n' -a locationfile.txt head -vn -0 > newfile
```

(the `-n -0` tells `head` to output all lines except the first 0 i.e. all lines).

Answer (score 3):

Another Perl approach:

```
$ perl -le 'do{print $_,`cat $_`,"\"\"";} for <>' locationfile.txt
text
text
text
""
text
text
text
""
text
text
text
""
```

That's using a bit of Perl magic and might need an explanation. The `-l`  removes trailing newlines from each input line and adds a newline to each `print` call. The `-e` is how you give a script to `perl`.

Now, `<>` is "the contents of the input file split into an array". So, `do {foo} for <>` will run `foo` on each line of the input file. Inside that `for` loop, the special variable `$_` is assigned to each input line. The `` `command` `` syntax will run `command` in the default shell (a system call) and return its output. So, `cat $_` will `cat` each filename in `locationfile.txt`.

Altogether, `` print $_,`cat $_`,"\"\"" `` will print the file name (currently in `$_`), the result of the `cat` (the file's contents) and then `""` (but we need to escape those, so `\"\"`).

In other words, that script means "read each input line, print it, `cat` the file it contains and print a `""` after each file.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add `echo "$line"` to your loop:

```
cat locationfile.txt | while read line; do echo "$line" && cat "$line"; done
```

Comment: You could also add `&& echo '""'` after `cat` to match user's desired output :)

Comment: This did exactly what I wanted!!! Now I will add in a check file as @Kusalananda said

Answer (score 2):

AWK approach via `system()` function. We make up the command string via `sprintf` and pass it on to `system()`

```
$ awk '{print $0; cmd=sprintf("cat \"%s\"",$0);system(cmd); print "\"\""}' filenames.txt                                 
/home/xieerqi/input1.txt
Hello, I am input file #1
And this is second line of the text
""
/home/xieerqi/input2.txt
And I am input file #2
Roses are red, violets are blue
AWK is awesome, Python is too
""
/etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
""
```

And Perl approach , but with opening file within the code:

```
$ perl -ne 'chomp; open($fh,$_) or die;print "$_\n";while($line = <$fh>){ print $line; print "\"\"\n" if eof}' filenames>
/home/xieerqi/input1.txt
Hello, I am input file #1
And this is second line of the text
""
/home/xieerqi/input2.txt
And I am input file #2
Roses are red, violets are blue
AWK is awesome, Python is too
""
/etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
""
```